# Python3 - change pattern A to B using lowest weight

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

So i have path A and B and weights of objects in path, for example:

```
A = [5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9]
B = [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5]
```

and weights, for example:

```
W = {1:1000, 2:500, 3:200, 4:400, 5:700, 6:250, 7:100, 8:50, 9:900}
```

and I want to replace A to B with using lowest weight,
for example if we want to replace 6 and 8, the used weight is: 50+250=300

what algorithm of sorting should i use etc?

example:

```
 IN [5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9] swap 4,2 weight = 400+500=900 
    [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9] swap 5,2 weight=700+500=1200 
    [2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9] swap 8,7 weight=50+100=150
    [2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 7, 8, 6, 9] swap 3,5 weight=200+7000=900 
    [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9] swap 5,9 weight=700+900=1600
    [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5] == B, sum = 900+1200+150+900+1600=4750
```

Comment: Please explain a little more. The question is unclear. What is the output that you expect?

Comment: The output should be minimum weight used to sort list A to B

Comment: I love such type of algorithmic puzzle. I will try it.

Comment: Please can you explain how list A is replaced with B. does every element of list A is replaced with every element of list B? I think by doing this List A will be changed to list B. And if this to be done then the weights of all the combinations should be the same. Please elaborate it little more

Comment: It is a fairly complicated question if takes as simple logic puzzle. First I have to figure out what should be the algorithm and I will code it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general way to do this is using graph search like [dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). The basic principle is that you keep building up a graph of the path (swaps) with the least accumulated cost (weight). If you keep exploring from the nodes in the graph with the least accumulated cost it is guaranteed that each new node is reached with the minimum possible accumulated cost. In the case of A* you use a heuristic function that estimates the remaining cost to reach the goal, which results in the need to explore less.

Here is one implementation of an A* like search and a function to recover the intermediate states.

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def search(start, goal, next_nodes, heuristic, hash_f):
    # start: starting node.
    # goal: goal node.
    # next_nodes: function of node and corresponding accumulated cost, 
    # should return iterable with new possible nodes and corresponding accumulated costs.
    # heuristic: function of node, should return an estimation of the remaining cost smaller than the true remaining cost.
    # hash_f: function of node, should return a hashable value.

    # (cost + heuristic, cost, start node, parent node)
    queue = [(0, 0, start, None)]
    # Dictionary representing minimum cost graph with visited nodes, their parent and cost
    minimum_graph = {} 

    while queue:
        _, node_cost, node, parent = heappop(queue)
        node_hash = hash_f(node)
        if node_hash in minimum_graph: continue
        minimum_graph[node_hash] = (parent, node_cost)

        if node == goal:
            return node_cost, minimum_graph

        for n, c in next_nodes(node, node_cost):
            if hash_f(n) not in minimum_graph:
                c_min = heuristic(n, goal)
                heappush(queue, (c + c_min, c, n, node))

    # Fail
    return None, minimum_graph

def get_path(start, goal, minimum_graph, hash_f):
    S = []
    C = []
    p = goal
    while p is not None:
        p_hash = hash_f(p)
        S.append(p)
        C.append(minimum_graph[p_hash][1])
        p = minimum_graph[p_hash][0]
    S.reverse()
    C.reverse()
    return S, C
```

The following function gives the next possible states and associated costs for the problem specified

```
def next_nodes(n, c):
    nodes = []
    for i in range(len(n)):
        for j in range(len(n)):
            if i == j: continue
            n_new = n.copy()
            n_new[i] = n[j]
            n_new[j] = n[i]
            c_new = c + W[n[i]] + W[n[j]]
            nodes.append((n_new, c_new))
    return nodes
```

To improve the search performance a heuristic is used which as long as it underestimates the remaining cost to sort the array will still result in the lowest cost. Directly moving without swapping is one possible heuristic for this problem.

```
def heuristic(n, goal):
    h = 0.0
    for i in range(len(n)):
        if n[i] != goal[i]:
            h += W[n[i]]
    return h
```

A list is not hashable but a tuple is, so a possible hash function to keep track of already visited states is

```
def hash_f(n):
    return tuple(n)
```

This can then be used as

```
A = [5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9]
B = [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5]
W = {1:1000, 2:500, 3:200, 4:400, 5:700, 6:250, 7:100, 8:50, 9:900}

cost, minimum_graph = search(A, B, next_nodes, heuristic, hash_f)
swaps, costs = get_path(A, B, minimum_graph, hash_f)

print(cost)
print(swaps)
```

which outputs

```
3350
[[5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9], [5, 4, 2, 1, 8, 3, 7, 6, 9], [5, 4, 2, 1, 9, 3, 7, 6, 8], [8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 3, 7, 6, 5], [2, 4, 8, 1, 9, 3, 7, 6, 5], [2, 8, 4, 1, 9, 3, 7, 6, 5], [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5], [2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 8, 6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You first should decide what is considered "movement". Are swaps required or can you move a piece in isolation?

For example, if you had a sparse array without boundaries, can you move 5 in A from the beginning to the end without affecting any other piece? Is there unlimited space between any two pieces such that you don't need to "separate them" (move one left and the other right)?

If that's the case, then I believe your problem reduces to finding the minimum number of required movements, which is selection sort - for each element of A, find the position of where to move it in B. Any implementation of quicksort, merge sort, bubble sort would imply ordering and require too many movement swaps

First few iterations

```
[5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9]
[  , 4, 2, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9, 5]  # move 5 to the end, weight=700
[  ,  , 2, 4, 1, 3, 8, 7, 6, 9]  # move 4 between 2 and 1, weight+=400
```

Comment: I think he means two numbers are to be swapped while sorting.

Comment: The question only asked what algorithm. Didn't explicitly limit to swapping

Comment: But In his he shows how to sort. And he does swapping there

Comment: I interpreted that as an example, not part of the question requirements